# R: Linking values from datasets and filling in corresponding values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with information about the gender of individuals. I have a second dataframe with observations about these individuals and I want to fill in the corresponding gender for each individual.

```
a <- data.frame(Individual = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
            Gender = c("M","M","F","F","M","F","M","M"))

b <- data.frame(Individual = c(2, 1, 5, 2, 8, 8, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7),
            Gender = c(NA))
```

What R code can I use to bring information about the gender of Individual from data.frame a and fill it into the Gender column of data.frame b, given the order and the length of the two data.frames are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `match`

```
b$Gender <- a$Gender[match(b$Individual, a$Individual)]
```

Another option would be to use `merge`.

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(a), Individual)[b['Individual']]
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. This works for the example dataset, but when I use the code on my entire dataset it says NULL. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment/question. I got your code to work just fine. Thanks so much!